# Good PowerShell Tutorials for SharePoint People?

Tags: powershell

For those of us new to SharePoint 2010 and now needing to do much of our work through PowerShell, not knowing PowerShell really well.  What have you used to get up to speed on PowerShell? Thanks!

Comment: Good answers, I like the answer given as it's well...more Sharepoint-ish :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend these links and this book (and no I am not the author):

Links:

http://www.u2u.info/Blogs/karine/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=9
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/zach/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=7

Book:

[http://www.amazon.com/PowerShell-Microsoft-SharePoint-2010-Administrators/dp/0071747974](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071747974)

Answer (score 3):

The [PowerScripting Podcast](http://powerscripting.wordpress.com/) is pretty nice to get through the basics and then general PowerShell. Start from the beginning though as the cmdlets covered in the first 2-3 shows are invaluable (not counting show 0 here).

This is a pretty good starter level post on PowerShell and SharePoint by the resource I send all of my questions: [SharePoint 2010, PowerShell what’s the deal?](http://codygros.wordpress.com/2010/06/21/sharepoint-2010-powershell-whats-the-deal/)

Oh and I almost forgot the free ebook at http://powershell.com

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few links to get you going -

Practical Windows PowerShell for SharePoint 2010 (a must read)
http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=362

PowerShell and SharePoint 2010 love story – Part 1  (more good links at the end of the article)
http://vspug.com/marwantarek/2009/11/27/powershell-and-sharepoint-2010-love-story-part-1/

SharePoint 2010 PowerShell Cheat Sheet
http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/sharepoint-2010-powershell-cheat-sheet/